# Store/save received push notifications in activity

Tags: java, android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have developed an app which is receiving notifications from firebase cloud messsaging.I want to save/store all these received notifications in any activity say(NotificationActivity),which displays all the notifications previously received.

I am opening MainActivity on clicking the push notification.I want to store the description and title.

Answer (score 2):

You can send it to any activity using Intents here is the details answer

[How to pass text from notification to another activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27657389/how-to-pass-text-from-notification-to-another-activity)

If you want to save them you can use either sharedprefs or sqlite database